# Getting Encrypted Request and Response while recording FlexCube Application through jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We are recording a FlexCube application through jmeter.

I am getting encrypted request and response data. Because of this reason we are not able to correlate values or even read the data for assertions.

[Request Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfBPp.png) [Response Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4RFG.png)

We wont be able to get the decryption logic and it is not possible to disable. I understand this being a core banking application the requests and response are always encrypted.
Can you suggest any workarounds for this or if there is any other way to record this kind of application?

[Request Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfBPp.png)[Response Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4RFG.png)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like request and response are [Base64-encoded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64):

[image]

So you could use [__base64Encode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Encodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) function to encode the request and [__base64Decode()](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#base64Decodesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-0-font-sup) function to decode the response.

These functions can be installed as a part of **Custom JMeter Functions** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

The encoded data can be extracted from the response using i.e. [XPath2 Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations)